# Jekyll site.categories is empty

Tags: jekyll

I have tried this code `{{site.categories | inspect}}` in default.html, but it returns empty space like this `{}`.

My post has a front matter that includes `categories: apple`.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

oh i found..

My jekyll theme post was referenced from 'docs' folder, but jekyll said every posts should be placed in _post folder. so jekyll `site` variable could not read categories of posts in docs folder.